# postgresql json data return key with max value

Tags: json, postgresql

I have json data stored something like this:

```
{"values":{"a":0.65, "b":0.35}}
```

I want to return the key which has the largest value in "values"

So in above case, 
I want to return:

```
a
```

since it has the largest value

Some of the rows have no values in the data which will have:

```
{}
```

as a default

I need to handle those entries with {} and return Null as well.

Answer (score 4):

With sample data:

```
create temporary table tmp as
  select '{"values":{"a":0.65, "b":0.35}}'::json as j;
insert into tmp values ('{}'::json);
```

You could do something like:

```
select (
  select key from json_each_text(j::json->'values')
  order by value::float desc limit 1
) as k
from tmp;
```